# Printful Oauth Api Prod. Upload

Tags: api, rest, curl, oauth-2.0

Description:

> **Oki, i am trying to upload products to printful via api**

|> __ they changed to oauth and the docs are not matching anymore

|> __ the functionality itself is in their docs, but i cant get it to auth

|> __ their dev support was not helpful and i am not a api person

Assets:

=>> https://developers.printful.com/docs/#section/Products-API-examples/Create-a-new-Sync-Product

=>> https://developers.printful.com/docs/#operation/createSyncProduct

Code:

> heres my error and code basically directly from their docs:

```
{"code":200,"result":"Welcome to the Printful API","extra":[]}

{"code":400,"result":"This API endpoint applies only to Printful stores based on the 
Manual Order / API platform. 
Find out more at Printful API docs.","error":{"reason":"BadRequest","message":
"This API endpoint applies only to Printful stores based on the Manual Order 
/ API platform. Find out more at Printful API docs."}}% 




# Authorized CURL request  with Basic auth
curl -X GET 'https://api.printful.com/' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN'


curl --location --request POST 'https://api.printful.com/store/products' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer SAMEtOKEN' \
--data-raw '{
    "sync_product": {
        "name": "T-Shirt",
        "thumbnail": "https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    },
    "sync_variants": [
        {
            "retail_price": 21.00,
            "variant_id": 4011,
            "files": [
                {
                    "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1"
                },
                {
                    "type": "back",
                    "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "retail_price": 21.00,
            "variant_id": 4012,
            "files": [
                {
                    "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1"
                },
                {
                    "type": "back",
                    "url": "https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

To save anyone else the headache:

The Printful 'Create Product' and similiar API calls don't work with shops created via the automatic API integrations:

[image: Screenshot from Printful store creation page]

As far as I'm aware there is no workaround, but if I find one I'll update here. The name is a bit misleading, as the 'Sync Products' seem to describe products capable of syncing with external services. However you are limited to the [ECommerce Platform Sync](https://developers.printful.com/docs/#tag/Ecommerce-Platform-Sync-API) API calls. It seems to be possible to modify an existing one, but that doesn't help much for GUI-free automation.

Maybe you can you create a number of placeholders as 'Drafts' and modify, but haven't gotten that running myself yet.